Positive mass theorem and Seiberg-Witten equations
Apologies for not a very rigorous question. I came across this PhD thesis by XIAO ZHANG, a student of Yau. From the thesis:
"We also investigate some
basic facts on Spin$^c$ structure on $4$-dimensional manifolds, and define the hypersurface
Spin$^c$ structure. For complete Riemannian $4$-dimensional manifold with Ricci curvature
bounded from below and nonnegative scalar curvature, we show that any $C^2$-solution of
Seiberg-Witten equations is reducible. This generalizes an observation of Witten on finite
energy solutions on $R^2$. The motivation is to try finding some relations between the
positive mass conjecture and the Seiberg-Witten theory. They are still unclear."
My question would be if there's any known idea or reference how Seiberg-Witten and the positive mass theorem can be related and how should one go about finding them if indeed they are related?

Why not ask Zhang directly. His contact information is here: https://gxcmr.gxu.edu.cn/info/1096/1061.htm.

There is none to my understanding, except the analysis and vanishing-proofs (involving Dirac operator) are related. Zhang's comment is only some trivial observation of non-$L^2$ solutions (and there are other such observations such as https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003125).
